# Apache POI issue TransformerFactory does not recognise attribute

Tags: java, xml, apache-poi, sax

An exception is being thrown after calling Apache POI's POIXMLDocument.write() method.
I tried both IcedTea and OpenJDK java 8 with the same results.
Below is th stack trace. Any help will be appreciated!

[org.apache.poi.util.XMLHelper]W SAX Feature unsupported [log suppressed for 5 minutes]http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/property/accessExternalSchema java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: TransformerFactory does not recognise attribute 'http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/property/accessExternalSchema'.   at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.setAttribute(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:471)    at org.apache.poi.util.XMLHelper.trySet(XMLHelper.java:280)     at org.apache.poi.util.XMLHelper.getTransformerFactory(XMLHelper.java:222)  at org.apache.poi.util.XMLHelper.newTransformer(XMLHelper.java:227)     at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.StreamHelper.saveXmlInStream(StreamHelper.java:56)  at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.ZipContentTypeManager.saveImpl(ZipContentTypeManager.java:69)  at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.ContentTypeManager.save(ContentTypeManager.java:452)   at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.saveImpl(ZipPackage.java:520)    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.save(OPCPackage.java:1514)   at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocument.write(POIXMLDocument.java:227)

Comment: this is fixed, but not yet integrated in POI: [XMLBEANS-564](https://issues.apache.org/jira/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/XMLBEANS-564)

Comment: Thanks. I was not referring to the excessive log issue but to the Exception being thrown: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: TransformerFactory does not recognise attribute 'http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/property/accessExternalSchema'.

Answer (score 2):

A solution that worked for me (just blocks the WARN msg from being output):

```
//  block poi 5.1.0 outputting '... accessExternalSchema' WARN msg
// (https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=65326)

    static { 
        org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Configurator.setLevel("org.apache.poi.util.XMLHelper", Level.ERROR);
    }

    :
    Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(excelFile, null, true);    
    :
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it.

For some reason if I call System.setProperty("org.apache.poi.util.POILogger", "org.apache.poi.util.SystemOutLogger" ); before trying to write the document, it fails. I removed that (old) line of code and now everything is working fine.